# Given a symmetrical matrix $A$ and a diagonal matrix $D$, determine an orthogonal matrix such that $Q^TAQ=D$

Tags: vector-spaces, vectors

> Given the symmetrical matrix A and the diagonal matrix D:
>
> $$A = \begin{pmatrix}
>         2 & -\frac{1}{2}\sqrt{3} \\
>         -\frac{1}{2}\sqrt{3} & 1 \\
>         \end{pmatrix},$$
>
> $$D = \begin{pmatrix}
>         \frac{1}{2} & 0 \\
>         0 & \frac{5}{2} \\
>         \end{pmatrix}$$

For the matrix to be orthogonal, its determinant has to be either $-1$ or $1$, but I don't know how to proceed.

Comment: Hint: eigenvalue and eigenvector

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want an orthogonal $Q$ such that $A=QDQ^\top$.

As others have hinted, note that $D$ contains the eigenvalues of $A$. The corresponding eigenvectors are the columns of $Q$. To see this, suppose $q_1$ is the first column of $Q$. Then
\begin{align}
Aq_1
&= QDQ^\top q_1\\
&= QD\begin{bmatrix}1\\0\end{bmatrix} & \text{orthogonormal columns}\\
&= Q \frac{1}{2} \begin{bmatrix}1\\0\end{bmatrix}\\
&= \frac{1}{2} q_1.
\end{align}
Similarly, $Aq_2=\frac{5}{2} q_2$.

So, to finish the problem, we just need to find two eigenvectors of $A$, scale them so that they have unit norm, and then $Q$ will have these two vectors as its columns.

The eigenvectors of $A$ can be found by finding a vector in the nullspace of $A-\lambda I$ for $\lambda=1/2$ and $\lambda=5/2$.